# Force Removal of Exchange and External Outlook Connectivity

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, outlook, rpc

I have just performed a force removal of an erroring `Exchange 2010` server from an Exchange organisation, which involved performing a cleanup in Active Directory to remove the server properly as we couldn't uninstall Exchange cleanly.

This server previously hosted all mailboxes, but I was lucky and could move them to a newly built `Exchange 2010 SP3 server`.

Everything is working quite well internally on the new Exchange server, however I'm having issues with certain external Outlook clients connecting.

We are using RPC over HTTP `Outlook Anywhere`, and it works well when I configure the Exchange server connection as `NewExchange.domain.local`.

The problem I'm getting is that quite a few users still have their outlook configured to connect to `OldExchange.domain.local` which has been forcefully removed due to issues defined above.
These clients now cannot connect to their mailbox externally (it works internally).

I have internal DNS entries to pointing `OldExchange.domain.local` to `NewExchange.domain.local`

The error I receive when I configure an external Outlook client is that it cannot contact the Exchange server (I have tried to replicate the issues the users are having by using `OldExchange.domain.local` - I am under the impression that after a successful connection this should update iself)

I am using `NTLM` Authentication, and IIS seems to be configured correctly.

Using testexchangeconnectivity.com I get the following error when I perform the Outlook tests:

```
Attempting to ping the MAPI Mail Store endpoint with identity: OldExchange.domain.local:6001.
The attempt to ping the endpoint failed.

Additional Details

The RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE error (0x6ba) was thrown by the RPC Runtime process.
Elapsed Time: 1688 ms.
```

In the Exchange organisation, only `NewExchange` exists as a server.

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not your firewall? A new server implies a new internal ip address, which implies that any Exchange related firewall service and NAT rules need to be modified relevant to the new server.

Comment: Yes I'm positive, I've re-mapped every port forward from the old internal IP address to the new internal IP - and have confirmed that even the ports such as 6000-6004 are all mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this going.
I decided to add the old server name to the (automatically generated) `ValidPorts` registry key since the `OldExchange` server was missing in there.

After doing this and restarting the services, everything was working as expected.